# customizing default login / regisration module of joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to Joomla. I would like to change the registration page coming with the login module,  i would like to add extra fields to it and change its appearance.  I might need to take the shipping address by adding four extra textboxes. Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Joomla comes with a profile plugin which extends the current registration form. However, if you need additional registration features, you will need to look into using an extension. Check the Joomla Extensions Directory

Answer (score 0):

For adding extra field to user a little idea is:

--> add your required field to .xml file of user component.

--> add appropriate field in database also.

--> code for saving that extra field.

You can refer these links which helps you a lot

http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/joomla/general-topics/40-joomla-25-extending-users-data-with-custom-fields

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile/profile-plugin-parameters

Hope this will helps you.